# rails how to call a controller action on running local server from command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, localhost

I read that it is not a good practice. But I'm ok with it. 
I am now calling the action from the browser url with a route to the action but I would like to be able to call directly from the command line without opening the browser. I do not want to call the action when I start the server, as I may need to run different actions and/or several times in each session.

Comment: Might be a little irrelevant, but why do you want to do that? And why not use tests/rspec instead?

Comment: @angkiki Its just my scraping setup. Lots of manual/frequent adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `curl` to create http requests from command line.